# Build an HTML5 game - No Starch

Tags: javascript

I do not understand the || and {} at the end of the first line here. Please could you explain.

```
var BubbleShoot = window.BubbleShoot || {};
BubbleShoot.Game = (function($){
var Game = function(){
var curBubble;
```

Comment: If the `window.BubbleShoot` exists, then `BubbleShoot` will be set to it. Otherwise it will set `BubbleShoot` to a blank object.

Comment: Perhaps a review of [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) and [object initializers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) is in order?

Comment: I think you're getting down-votes because the title of your post is extremely misleading compared to your actual question. A better title might be _what do || and {} mean in Javascript_ to which there are a number of related or duplicate posts.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I will look into object initializers. Was jumping into this without much Javascript knowledge.

Comment: OK thanks, for my further posts will refine the title a bit further!

Answer (score 3):

`||` is the "or" operator in JavaScript. It returns the value on the left if the value on the left is truthy, otherwise it returns the value on the right.

`undefined` and `null`, are both falsey values in JavaScript, so if `window.BubbleShoot` is one of these, the first line of your code will set the value of `BubbleShoot` to be `{}`, which is an empty JavaScript object on which you can set properties like `Game` as shown in your second line of code.

Answer (score 2):

The || is the JavaScript operator for 'OR', and the {} is defining a new, empty hash;

Essentially, it's equivalent to the following:

```
if (window.BubbleShoot != null && window.BubbleShoot != undefined) {
    BubbleShoot = window.BubbleShoot;
} else {
    BubbleShoot = {}; // new, empty hash
}
```